# Shredding XML in SQL Server from NTEXT

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

Hopefully this is an easy one for experts :)

I have a column containing XML (at the bottom of this post) - the column is of `ntext` datatype.
Rather than displaying the entire XML string in a column, I want to shred it into multiple columns. The database is SQL Server 2008 R2. Column datatype cannot be changed (MS application DB)

I've tried multiple variations of xpath queries but I keep getting null values. Hopefully it's just the way I'm referencing it which is incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can't get my head around XML it seems (not through lack of trying!):

XML (example from one record in the result - I've split it up for ease of reading):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  
<q1:ErrorInfo ErrorCode="1073744938" DetailedCode="0" DetailedSource="0" ExceptionDetails="" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/dls/GenericAgentStatus.xsd">    
<q1:Parameter Name="datasourceid" Value="48c3db91-4ba9-46a5-820b-a2ab2c0733aa" />    
<q1:Parameter Name="doesalertneedstroubleshootuiformoredetails" Value="False" />    
<q1:Parameter Name="failurecount" Value="1" />    
<q1:Parameter Name="customparameterformom" Value="86924" />    
<q1:Parameter Name="datasourcename" Value="servername\database1" />    
<q1:Parameter Name="protectedgroup" Value="ProtectionGroup1 Servers - servername.domain" />    
<q1:Parameter Name="servername" Value="servername.domain" />  
</q1:ErrorInfo>
```

SQL which I'm working with (null values returned):

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/dls/GenericAgentStatus.xsd' as q1)                        
select cast(ErrorXml as XML).value('(/q1:ErrorInfo/q1:Parameter[6]/q1:value[0]/text())[1]','varchar(MAX)') as [servername]
from
target_table
```

At the end of all this I would like to split out servername, protected group, datasource name.

Any pointers on where I'm going wrong would be massively appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Generally speaking, in XPath you use `@attributeName` to select XML attribute. Try this XPath : `/q1:ErrorInfo/q1:Parameter[6]/@Value`

Comment: Unless you are REALLY interested in exactly the value of the *sixth* parameter and not the one relating to *protectedgroup* you should use: `/q1:ErrorInfo/q1:Parameter[@Name='protectedgroup']/@Value`.

Comment: Magic! Both of these worked really well and I'm torn on who to award the answer to. I have decided to use the first answer from har07 although using Marcus's answer would be better for other people reading my script - in my case it's not as important for anyone to understand what I'm trying to achieve.  Thanks to both of you for your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Well unfortunatley, it seems I can't mark a comment as an answer - took a look on SO forums and this is by design.  Kudos to both commentors for this post.

The solution I'm using is from har07 but I did try the solution from Marcus and that worked perfectly as well.

My reworked code now looks like this ... and works perfectly:

```
    select cast(ls.ErrorXml as XML).value('(/q1:ErrorInfo/q1:Parameter[6]/@Value)[1]','varchar(MAX)') as [ServerName],
cast(ls.ErrorXml as XML).value('(/q1:ErrorInfo/q1:Parameter[5]/@Value)[1]','varchar(MAX)') as [ProtectedGroup],
cast(ls.ErrorXml as XML).value('(/q1:ErrorInfo/q1:Parameter[4]/@Value)[1]','varchar(MAX)') as [DataSourceName],
```

...

Thanks loads again - saved me so much time and sanity!

Comment: Converted my comment to answer so you can mark it. I'm not experienced in the SQL part though, so I think this answer is also useful in a way

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, in XPath you use `@attributeName` to select XML attribute, you can try this way :

```
/q1:ErrorInfo/q1:Parameter[6]/@Value
```